# Convert Stanza to Paragraph in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to create a python script that converts a stanza to a paragraph. Something of this sort:

```
My mother’s maids, when they did sew and spin,
They sang sometimes a song of the field mouse,
That for because their livelihood was but so thin.

Would needs go seek her townish sister’s house.
Would needs She thought herself endured to much pain:
The stormy blasts her cave so sore did souse…
```

to become a paragraph like this:

My mother’s maids, when they did sew and spin, They sang sometimes a song of the field mouse, That for because their livelihood was but so thin. Would needs go seek her townish sister’s house. Would needs She thought herself endured to much pain: The stormy blasts her cave so sore did souse…

Comment: It looks like you want to collapse consecutive newlines into a single space.  Look at [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for regex, not python. Replace `\n+` with  (a single space).

[Here’s a link to Regexr](https://regexr.com/3idvc)

Comment: Thank you. Was so simple but I overlooked.

Comment: Thank you, could you accept my answer if it helped?